# keyboard typing number 6 itself

Tags: keyboard, automation, typing

I don't know what the hell happened with my laptop but it just keeps on typing number 6 itself. I tried to disable the key with KeyTweak and many other apps but it didn't worked. I can't type anything properly.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: What happens if you disable NumLock?

Answer (score -2):

Go to start menu, type device manager press enter, click on device manager, find keyboard in device manager, click on + sign for drop down menu to disable keyboard driver reboot should be required to make this permanent or uninstall it.

Comment: tried it not working.also tried formatting laptop but still not working